# Android Studio not showing dangerous permissions warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, lint, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an Android Studio project and I'm trying to update it to Android 23. I changed the target to 23 in build.gradle and I was expecting Android Studio or lint to show warnings in the code blocks that need to use dangerous permissions. But neither Android Studio or Lint are showing the warnings. Does anybody know what could be the reason of this problem? 
I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: using version 1.5 of both Android studio and gradle android plugin but still not working. have you found any way to make it work?

Comment: Definitely working for me in AS 1.5.1. The code is underlined in red and pops up a warning something like "Requires a permission that could be rejected by user: code should check...". I surrounded the code with a checkSelfPermission conditional and the warning was removed.

Comment: @gordonwd I'm using AS 1.5.1 too, but I don't see any Lint warnings. Do I've to change Lint settings?

Comment: I don't very much about the internals of Studio or Lint and have no answer for you. I know that if I turned on all warnings, my code would be full of them since it's an app that I've been maintaining since Android 2.1 and it's become pretty hacked up with all the enhancements and updates!

Comment: Hi did you resolve this problem. If yes, Please post your answer. It would helpful for someone like me.

Comment: It is not even working 2.1.2. Did you find a workaround?