# Lint in Android Studio 1.5.1 is not working for missing permissions detection

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently, I'm in the process of migrating my app to target API 23.

It takes me a while to figure out why `accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google")` no longer work. This is due to new Marshmallow permission model - http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1

According to http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks, I'm expecting lint able to warn me for the following code, based on **MissingPermission**

```
public static String getEmail() {
    Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS; // API level 8+
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MyApplication.instance());
    Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

    for (Account account : accounts) {
        if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
            String possibleEmail = account.name;
            return possibleEmail;
        }
    }
}
```

I checked the lint installed in my system. I can confirm **MissingPermission** feature is there via

```
c:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624\sdk\tools\lint.bat --show
```

But, I received no warning in Android Studio. I had checked the lint setting in Android Studio.

[image]

It seems that 
I don't see any "Missing permission" option there.

Is there anything wrong with my Android Studio settings?

I can see EverNote team once file a bug report regarding lint checking on missing permissions - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182165 But it is fixed since Android Studio 1.4

Comment: nice one, same here. I'm beginning to suspect someone silently commented it, I'm pretty sure this was working, showing a 'blocking' lint error. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611120/android-studio-not-showing-dangerous-permissions-warnings is related, but with AS1.4.1.

Comment: try running 'gradlew lint check MissingPermission' from the root of your project...I'm getting a "Task 'MissingPermission' not found in root project" error message. So IMHO that lint check is not present in android studio using com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 (November 2015)

Comment: It is not even working in 2.1.2. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2

I do have a couple of missing permission settings in different categories have you checked other categories?

[image: Lint permissions]

**Edit:** `MissingPermission` does not seem to be any of these.

Comment: don't think so... The doc's description is: MissingPermission
-----------------
Summary: Missing Permissions

Priority: 9 / 10
Severity: Error
Category: Correctness

This check scans through your code and libraries and looks at the APIs being
used, and checks this against the set of permissions required to access those
APIs. If the code using those APIs is called at runtime, then the program will
crash.

Comment: You are right checking out one by one the permissions of the my screenshot none of them covers or implies that it works for `MissingPermission` which means that the issue persists in Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2?! How do we check the Lint version?

Comment: It seems like that this check has 'silently' been removed from AS's lint

Comment: with 'lint --version'. But i suspect the problem to be in lint's PROFILE, rather that version, since we can't find the rule despite official doc http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks

Comment: `lint: version 24.4.1` I guess this is some other versioning number because it was not even close to `1.4`. I also confirmed that `lint --show` lists the `MissingPermission` have you tried to run lint report via the `cmd`?